# Rails - How to password reset (without email confirm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and I want to offer users the feature to change password in their user page. Requiring their old password and setting a new one. However, I have no idea how to accomplish this.

There is a Railscasts episode on resetting password through email but I dont want to do it with email.

I generated a Password Update controller. But I know I am making a terrible mistake. Hopefully you guys can point it out. And hopefully this question wasn't too confusing.

**password updates controller**

```
  class PasswordUpdateController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end
  end
```

**new password_update**

```
 %h1
 = form_for @user, :url => password_update_path(params[:id]) do |f|
   .field
     = f.label :old_password
     = f.password_field :password
   .field
     = f.label :password
     = f.password_field :password
   .field
     = f.label :password_confirmation
     = f.password_field :password_confirmation
   .actions
     = f.submit "Update Password"
```

> Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/password_update/1"

**routes.rb**

> TootApp::Application.routes.draw do
>
> get "sessions/new"
>
> get "static_pages/home"
>
> get "static_pages/help"
>
> get "password_updates/new"
>
> resources :sessions
>
> resources :products
>
> resources :photos
>
> resources :password_update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you should use controllers. Password update should be an 'action' within a 'controller' and that controller, when it comes to user credentials, should rightfully be in the UsersController, where an 'update' action takes in parameters that you post from a form:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    ....
  end
end
```

And in your HTML form, you can just specify:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  ...
```

without even needing to specify the URL, since rails will implicitly provide you with the right URL in the background :)

And make sure to have your 'Routes' correctly setup like so:

```
resources :users
```

It basically sets up the RESTful routes for users. You can find out the routes it generates, by running the following in your console:

```
rake routes
```

Apart from hooking up your own user credential management features, why not try out the devise gem by Jose Valim, and pair it with SimpleForm gem.

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Hope this helps!